# can't use setUpTestData variable in setUp

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-tests

i define this line of code in
but i got self.user not define user
How can I use the variables defined in setUp func it?

```
    class TestSample(TestCase):
    
        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            super().setUpTestData()
            business = BusinessFactory()
            cls.user = business.main_owner
    
        def setUp(self):
            self.api_client = APIClient()
            self.client, self.token, self.user = self.client_login(
                self.api_client,
                phone=self.user
            )
```

Comment: You need to pass in the user first.

Comment: Maybe `self.user = business.main_owner` or just `user = business.main_owner`

Comment: Can you show the callstack and the real error message? I don't see why it should not work (assuming `TestCase` is a `django.test.TestCase`, of course), if `business.main_owner` gets you a valid user. It is strange though that you assign the user to a phone number...

Answer (score 1):

This problem solved.
If you want to use variables in several test functions, you should define them in this method

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    # Set up data for the whole TestCase
    cls.foo = Foo.objects.create(bar="Test")
    ...
```

**Attention** : these variables can not change during run test functions